# ASP.Net MVC3 Dynamic Form using ModelMetaData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a simple Edit page which will take a ViewModel passed from the controller.  Currently, the `ViewModel` is decorated with some attributes, and the `Edit.cshtml` works fine with the simple `@Html.EditorForModel()` and a submit button.

```
public class MySimpleViewModel {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What I need to do is alter the `ModelMetaData` based on the user's role and make certain properties read only.  Is it possible to modify the `ModelMetaData` in the controller so that `Name` will appear as if we had given the attribute `[HiddenInput(Display=true)]`?

For my application it isn't feasible to create a new model for each role type and the `Model` itself is the same.  What is the best approach?  I've tried the following to no avail.

```
public ViewResult Edit(Guid id) {
    var result = View( Service.GetByID( id ) );

    // Alter the result.ViewData.ModelMetaData here???

    return result;
}
```

When I check the `ModelMetaData` in the `View`, it doesn't have the changes I made in the controller.  What is a good way to do this?  I've read samples where people create a subclass of the `ModelMetaDataProvider` but I don't think that's exactly what I need or maybe I just don't get it.

Thank you

Comment: have you come up with a way to do this. I was looking to do the same thing. Maybe I should add a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Way late.. but here is an alternative though? At my last job we made our own templates for the  EditorForModel() helpers ... and in those you can have it check permissions and then either make a label or input. Just a thought.. just came across this post looking for more info on modelmetadata so figured id leave a comment :)